# Is the subset $[0, \sqrt2] ∩\mathbb{Q} ⊂ \mathbb{Q}$ closed, bounded, compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Letting $\mathbb{Q}$ be equipped with the Euclidean metric.

What I can work out is that it is bounded as its contained in the closed ball of radius ${\sqrt2}/{2}$ centred at ${\sqrt2}/{2} $.

Its not compact as it can be expressed as union of the two disjoint open sets $[0,{\sqrt2}/{2}) $and$ ({\sqrt2}/{2}, \sqrt2)$ (though I'm not sure if this makes it not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$ or just $\mathbb{R}$).

And its not closed as the sequence of truncations of $\sqrt2$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ converges to $\sqrt2$

Comment: I'm unsure about the open cover/finite subcover definition and how to apply it, (how to prove there is no finite subcover). A good explanation of this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is the intersection of a closed set in $\;\Bbb R\supset\Bbb Q\;$, and obvioulsy bounded as it is fully contained in $\;[0,\sqrt2]\;$ .

Comment: What is your definition of compactness? Is it sequential compactness?

Comment: @John It is that for every open cover, there exists a finite subcover.

Comment: @123454321: Thanks. Then Timbuc's answer give you good example of open cover.

Answer (score 2):

It is not closed (in $\Bbb R$)
 because of what you said. It is not compact because not closed in this space (and compactness is not related to the ambient subspace).

It is obviously bounded.

But what you wrote on compactness refers not to compactness, but connectedness.

edit: 
**let us prove it is closed in $\Bbb Q$**:

consider a sequence of rational numbers converging to some $x\in\Bbb Q$.
As $x_n\in [0,\sqrt 2]:=C$ and $C$ is closed, $x\in C$. Hence $x\in C\cap\Bbb Q$
(this is also the general proof that the intersection of any subspace with a closed/open set is closed/open *in the subset*).

Comment: Oh of course, forgot about connectedness.

Comment: I think it is closed?

Comment: It is closed **in** $\;\Bbb Q\;$ as an intersection of closed (in $\;\Bbb R\;$ and the wholse set $\;\Bbb Q\;$ .

Comment: well ,it would be nice if the downvoters could talk.

Comment: As stated in another comment, your answer is incorrect. This set is closed in the rationals.

Comment: When talk about closedness, it should be closed in $\mathbb Q$. (I did not downvote)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it was obvious the original question takes the ambient space in $\mathbb{Q}$ and not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mookid, don't expect that: many downvoters just don't justify their doing. I almost never downvote, and didn't in this case either, but I think your answer is wrong, or at least may be misleading, as the OP wrote $\;[0,\sqrt2]\cap\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\;$ ,so he's referring to this as a subset of the rationals, not the reals.

Comment: So is it closed or not? I dont see how my answer above is incorrect if it is in fact closed.

Comment: @123454321 Why do you ask that? Either you read and understood the comments/answers or you didn't. If you didn't then ask, but if you did understand them then there's no point to ask! And your answer is wrong because showing the set is or is not the union of two (open, closed, whatever) sets has nothing to do with compactness, as noted else where.

Comment: @123454321: Can you tell us what is your definition of closedness?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I made the correction.

Comment: @123454321 read my edited answer.

Comment: @Timbuc I said above that I had confused compactness with connectedness. That isnt the answer I was referring to anyway. I do not understand how the intersection of a closed set in R and Q is closed in Q. A closed set is a set containing all its limit points, and the sequence of truncations of $\sqrt2$, converges to $\sqrt2$, and so the limit of this sequence is not contained in the set.

Comment: @123454321 it is closed in $\Bbb Q$ as it retains its *rational* limits.

Comment: @123454321, Mookid already addressed in his last comment your doubt about clossednes, but it is **always** true that if we have a top. space $\;X\;$ and $\;Y\subset X\;$ *with the inherited topology*, then $\;A\subset Y\;$ is closed (in $\;Y\;$ , of course) iff we can write $\;A= Y\cap T\;$ , with $\;T\subset X\;$ **closed** (in $\;X\;$ ).

Answer (score 1):

About compact: take the open cover (and prove it is such)

$$\left\{\;\left(\frac1n\;,\;\;\sqrt2-\frac1n\right)\cap\Bbb Q\;\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}}$$

Resuming (see the comments): it is closed, bounded and not compact.

Comment: It is easy to prove that this is an open cover for the subset, but how do I prove there is no finite subcover?

Comment: @123454321, assume there there is... **but** observe the sets in this cover are embedded in each other: $$\left(\frac12\,,\,\sqrt2-\frac12\right)\subset\left(\frac13\,,\,\sqrt2-\frac13\right)\subset\ldots$$ so if there's a finite cover then...

Comment: But why can't we say that the single open set at n = ∞ covers the set, this is a finite number of sets and hence a finite open cover. I know you're right, I'm just a bit foggy on the definition.

Comment: @123454321 "At $\;n=\infty\;$"? There's no such a thing: infinity is not a number (at least not here and in this context).

Comment: This fails to be a cover, as $0$ does not lie in any of the sets.